PWM buck converter using IRFZ44N and BD139
Please help me with this circuit diagram 
I need to design a adjustable voltage supply 0-20V.
For that I want to use this circuit but somehow it's not working in my case. the PWM signal was generated by the Arduino. I have already fabricated the PCB for this design, but now it's not working. Please help me with this.
I have given too much time into this, please help, I even tried BC547 to drive the MOSFET but that also didn't work.
The possible reason could be the bad components, please someone reconstruct this circuit and let me know the results.

1N4007 is way too slow for that purpose for starters... And you can't drive a N channel FET like that, what you have is a source follower.

What does "not working" mean. Provide details, scope traces, voltage and current measurements etc. Obvious faults are that R44 is much too high to drive the MOSFET and the 1N4007 is too slow for use in this circuit. What about input decoupling - extremely important for a buck converter.

Princeintan - Hi, From your question, it seems this isn't your design. So where did the schematic come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. || If the source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage / PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then give full details of the source e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

One more issue: Pin 1 and 2 of Q2 are swapped.

You need to drive Q2's gate to higher than 24 V relative to ground, otherwise you're just making a source follower. And even if you were driving it high enough, a 10 kΩ pull-up resistor is way too large. You should have an active pull-up.

The first thing is the MOSFET. Q2 is an NMOS so it needs its gate voltage to be higher than the voltage at its source pin. A level translator with a BJT would work with a PMOS instead. So, either use a PMOS for Q2 or if you have to use IRFZ44N then change the driving method (e.g. bootstrapping or using a gate drive transformer).
One other thing is the freewheeling diode. The switching frequency is not given but if it's a few tens of kHz or higher then it's better to use a Schottky diode or a fast-recovery diode because 400x would be too slow.
And finally, the choke. I don't know what considerations are taken for inductance selection but, even though you can somehow adjust the voltage with the PWM duty cycle, if the load becomes lighter than a certain level then the operation mode will switch to DCM (discontinuous conduction mode) and in this mode, the output voltage will become load-dependent. This may become annoying because occasionally you'll find yourself constantly adjusting the duty cycle as the load current changes. The rest of the circuit is not given but you'll definitely need voltage feedback.

You should use another MOSFET ... like this one.
Here is a simulation with microcap v12.

Zener and resistors split the driving voltage for the MOSFET under 15 V (-Vgs max = 15 V).
Note that the output voltage is "non-linear" and it can "jump" at a higher voltage than input.
Regulation must take this into account ...
